# show_img() function not working in python

Tags: python, image, opencv

```
image = imread(r"sampleimage.jpg")
show_img(image)
```

---

```
NameError: name 'show_img' is not defined.
```

Please suggest me why it is happening?

Comment: There is no method named `show_img` in your code. You probably want to import it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using opencv by looking at your code

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("sampleimage.jpg")
cv2.imshow('image',image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```